# gnuplot histogram error: I cant produce no more than 1 line from data file

Tags: gnuplot

I'm experiencing this problem with gnuplot and I dont have a clue what might go wrong...
I was trying to create a histogram by passing values from a dat file:

```
machine1    1.04    1.11     1.09
machine2    0.12    0.16     0.126
machine3    1.478   1.358    1.306
```

with this .plt file:

```
set terminal x11 persist
set title "Average Load of current machines"
set style data linespoints
set ylabel "load"
set xlabel "machines"
set yrange [0:1.5]

plot "test.dat" using 2:xticlabel(1) w lp lw 2 t "1 min", \
     "" using 3  w lp lw 2 t "5 min", \
     "" using 4  w lp lw 2 t "15 min"
```

but unfortunately I only get the data for the first line (as points) omitting the rest lines  of the dat file...

[image: gnuplot histogram pic1]

On the other hand if I copy the data from the .dat file into the .plt file like that:

```
set terminal x11 persist
set title "Average Load of current machines"
set style data linespoints
set ylabel "load"
set xlabel "machines"
set yrange [0:1.5]

plot "-" using 2:xticlabel(1) w lp lw 2 t "1 min", \
     "" using 3  w lp lw 2 t "5 min", \
     "" using 4  w lp lw 2 t "15 min"
machine1    1.04    1.11     1.09
machine2    0.12    0.16     0.126
machine3    1.478   1.358    1.306
```

I get the proper result for all machines but only for the fisrt column omitting the rest columns...

[image: gnuplot histogram pic 2]

Any suggestion what might be wrong, please??

EDIT/SOLVED

well the problem was coming from bash where I built the dat file...
I was passing an \r character every time I wanted to add a new line of data. I had no idea that this is not gnuplot friendly... After a couple of days troubling I realised it...

PS thanks guys for your comments. I hope that this will help other newbies too so that they wont fell into same mistake...

Comment: Your first script works for me (gnuplot 4.4.2 on OSX).  What gnuplot version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The second version doesn't work because inline data must be repeated (unfortunately) ...

```
set terminal x11 persist
set title "Average Load of current machines"
set style data linespoints
set ylabel "load"
set xlabel "machines"
set yrange [0:1.5]

plot "-" using 2:xticlabel(1) w lp lw 2 t "1 min", \
     "" using 3  w lp lw 2 t "5 min", \
     "" using 4  w lp lw 2 t "15 min"
machine1    1.04    1.11     1.09
machine2    0.12    0.16     0.126
machine3    1.478   1.358    1.306
e
machine1    1.04    1.11     1.09
machine2    0.12    0.16     0.126
machine3    1.478   1.358    1.306 
e
machine1    1.04    1.11     1.09
machine2    0.12    0.16     0.126
machine3    1.478   1.358    1.306
e
```

The first version works on my computer, so I don't know what is wrong with that one...